# How can I invoke PaintEventArgs for results returned by EventArgs from Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services

I have this code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int size;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        size = 10;
    }

    private void runAutomat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var myMatrix = new int[size][];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            myMatrix[i] = new int[size];
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                myMatrix[i][j] = 0;
        }

        var cw = new MyWebService();

        var result = cw.FillMatrix(myMatrix, size);

    }
}
```

Next I want to draw grid for result, but I don't have idea how to send it to method with PaintEventArgs. For example something like this:

```
private void PB_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int cellSize = 2;

      for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
            for (int y = 0; y < size; ++y)
            {
                if (result [y, x].state == 1)
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Cyan), new Rectangle(y * cellSize, x * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize));
                else if (result [y, x].state == 2)
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), new Rectangle(y * cellSize, x * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize));

            }

}
```

I know it is incorrect and I need better solution.

Comment: Why not just store `result` in a form level variable and call `this.Refresh()`?

Comment: because: The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration

Comment: Don't use `var`, use the actual data type.

Comment: FillMatrix in MyWebService is returning my own type: Cell [][]. I'm not sure if i have access to Cell type which is on my local web service.

Comment: You must have access, otherwise you couldn't use the value at all.

Comment: MyWebService cw = new MyWebService(); cw.Cell cell = new cw.Cell();
It's not even working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the value of `result` as a form level variable and then call `this.Refresh()` to make the form redraw.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Guessing what the data type is:
    private int[,] _result;

    private void runAutomat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //snip
        _result = cw.FillMatrix(myMatrix, size);
        this.Refresh();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found temporary solution.

```
using WFConsume.localhost;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int size;
    private localhost.Cell [][]cells;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        size = 10;
    }
}

    private void runAutomat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var myMatrix = new int[size][];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            myMatrix[i] = new int[size];
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                myMatrix[i][j] = 0;
        }

        MyWebService cw = new MyWebService();

        cells = cw.FillMatrix(myMatrix, size);

    }
```

It's working in form level. Thank you DavidG for a tips!